# What is a good open source backup solution for users?

Tags: backup, open-source

We are currently using ahsay to run backups on end user systems that backup to our specified directories within the server. My question would be what is a good open source backup solution that is similar in the aspect of having a service run on an end users machines that communicates with the server?

Comment: It might be helpful if mentioned what OS this is to run on, and whether the backup is to a local file, tape device or something else. And whether it needs to support mulitple volumes. Does the list of backup targets change? Incremental or full backups?

Comment: Any reason it has to be open source? Is it purely cost based or for some other reason?

Comment: Are you looking for a push or a pull system? i.e. Will the data be pushed up from the client or pulled down from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the operating system, but if you are using Linux & the GNOME Desktop I recommend  [Déjà Dup](http://launchpad.net/deja-dup).

Comment: Sorry, ahsay is a linux based system. The client connects to the server via a secure public address daily. In regards to open source, yes, it is a cost and growth factor.

Answer (score 0):

More details re: your configuration would be extremely helpful, but [Amanda Community Edition](http://amanda.zmanda.com/) supports the client/server model I'm assuming you're looking for and has agents for Linux, Windows, and [with some work](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Installation/OS_Specific_Notes/Installing_Amanda_on_Mac_OS_X), Mac OS X.

Amanda also has a [BackupPC](http://www.zmanda.com/backuppc.html) solution with deduplication that looks to be a bit more lightweight for desktop backups, but I haven't tested it so I can't comment on it.